# Inconsistent of data between database and application Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am new to the world Ruby on Rails, and I'm having a problem (appearing to be simple).

Production in the database is deleted all records related to a person. To date, the database no records related to the name "John Smith".

In ruby on rails application, when I do a search of the deleted record, it returns only the name and date as shown below:

[image: Searching the deleted record]

This record was not to be displayed anywhere.

Are there any Ruby on Rails command to update the records that were manually deleted in the database?

Here are a few considerations that are configured in the project:

This inconsistency could be cached in the production environment? In the case could not be changed permanently, for best performance.

```
config.action_controller.perform_caching = true
```

It could then be the application in memory?

```
config.eager_load = true
```

Can help me solve and understand this problem?

Thanks.

Comment: http://shouldiblamecaching.com/

Comment: only perform_caching and eager_load in config file won't lead to this problem. Is that you implemented Fragment Caching ?

Comment: @LeonardoWong, I took over the project recently, the case went looking for possible places there may be some consideration to cache.

Answer (score -1):

You should check straight in Console what records are loaded and why is this recored loaded.

If you think it's caching, which i doubt, just restart web-server.
Most likely you still have object somewhere in Database and it's not fully delete.

Comment: Restarting web-server won't help with most caching schemes.

Comment: I deleted all records related to John Smith, shortly after rebooted the server, and the problem still persists.